# Condition on eigenvalues for a matrix product involving a non-negative definite matrix

Tags: matrices

In the matrix product $A=BC$ let $A$, $B$, $C$ be squared real matrices with the same dimensions, where $A$ and $C$ are symmetrical and $C$ is also positive definite.

Is there any set of conditions that $B$ must verify (especially on its eigenvalues) so that $A$ is non-negative definite (resp. positive definite)?

Comment: Do you think there are? Have you done any work so far?

Comment: Well, the solution seems trivial if B is symmetrical as well, since I just need for it to be non-negative definite, so the eigenvalues must be non-negative. I am mostly interested in how to extend, if possible, the reasoning to the case B is in general non symmetrical.

Comment: Ok, I think I got the hang of it. I could only prove a necessary condition for $B$: its eigenvalues must be real non-negative (resp. positive). Since $C$ is definite positive, its inverse $C^{-1}$ exists and it's definite positive ([similar question](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/211453/)), so the problem is the same as finding conditions on eigenvalues of a product of a positive definite and a non negative definite (resp.positive definite) matrix ([similar question](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1365079/))